# How to change a 2D character's sprite in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, 2d

Suppose I have a 2D pixel character like this:

[image]

and I want to know if there are some ways in Unity to edit this character's sprite to have movement or attack.

Answer (score 2):

I do believe you have to use the sequence of  the sprite to animate it

Answer (score 1):

No, not in Unity.  You have to use an image editor to make each frame of the animation yourself, and then use Unity to hook them all up into a cohesive, fluid, interactive motion.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an animation sequence for your character and simple add all of your animated (images)sprites in the sequence.

You can read more about animations from Unity's official tutorials here: [Introduction to Sprite Animations](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/introduction-to-sprite-animations#)